# Displaying Only the Items in the Cart?

Tags: php, html

So I need to display items that  were added on the Vend Page and are now in the cart array over onto the cart page in a list

```
 Array
 (
     [cart] => Array
    (
        [BRB] => 1
    )

)
```

Here is my code for the cart page that I'm working on:

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    foreach ($vend as $vendID => $items) {

 //if (array_search($vendID, $_SESSION['cart'])) {   

 echo "<article class ='cart' id='cart-$vendID'>";
 echo "<h1 class = 'item-h1' id = 'h1'>{$items['title']}</h1>";
 echo "<div class ='item-no'>";
 echo "<p class = 'pro-id'><b>Product ID:  </b>{$vendID}</p></div>";

 echo "<div class ='img-div'>";
 echo "<img src =../images/{$items['img']} alt='' height='196' width='200'></div>";

 echo "<div class='pricing'>";
 echo "<p><b>Price: $</b>{$items['price']}</p></div>";

echo "</article>";


//} 
  }
 }
```

I commented out code that I attempted but didn't work. So I need an IF statement which says, If the vendID is in the cart array display it in the list.

Some help is appreciated here as I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cart should be as follows:

```
$cart = array(
        [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1,
            [title] => "your title",
            [price] => 100,
            [img] => "name of the file",
        ),
        [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2,
            [title] => "your title",
            [price] => 200,
            [img] => "name of the file",
        )

    );
```

And Then Try as follows:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
foreach ($cart as $key => $items) { //$key = [0], [1] ....

    echo "<article class ='cart' id='cart-$key'>";
    echo "<h1 class = 'item-h1' id = 'h1'>".$items['title']."</h1>";
    echo "<div class ='item-no'>";
    echo "<p class = 'pro-id'><b>Product ID:  </b>".$items['item_id']."</p></div>";

    echo "<div class ='img-div'>";
    echo "<img src =../images/".$items['img']." alt='' height='196' width='200'></div>";

    echo "<div class='pricing'>";
    echo "<p><b>Price: $</b>".$items['price']."</p></div>";

    echo "</article>";

}
```

}

Mark, it accepted if it works.

Comment: this is the same code I have except I need an IF statement under foreach to say "only display an item from $cart if its selected on the vend page

Comment: add a field to the cart as follows: 
 [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1,
            [title] => "your title",
            [price] => 100,
            [img] => "name of the file",
            [selected] => "A",
        ),
        [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2,
            [title] => "your title",
            [price] => 200,
            [img] => "name of the file",
            [selected] => "B",
        )

And then apply the conditon

Comment: I should mention my  Array () field is showing in a debug module so i can't change it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)  ?
It checks if a value exists in an array.